# Android BottomSheetDialog can't show title even though I set a title

Tags: android

It's my very first time to use BottomSheetDialog,
the code is like this:

```
final BottomSheetDialog bottomSheetDialog = new BottomSheetDialog(this);
bottomSheetDialog.setTitle("title");
//bottomSheetDialog.setContentView(...)
bottomSheetDialog.show();
```

When I ran this code, the title didn't show.

Can you explain to me what happened to this code? Thank you ~

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you look into the source code of `android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetDialog` you will find, that inside it's constructor there is a line:

```
// We hide the title bar for any style configuration. Otherwise, there will be a gap
// above the bottom sheet when it is expanded.
supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

which clearly states, that Bottom sheet will not have title (with reason). (As of support library version 23.4.0)

Suggestion:
Make a title of the view inside the layout of bottom sheet.